# QueryTables.Add(Connection) ERROR , Expected '='

Tags: excel, vba

So, first of all, i am not familiar with VBA. I've been trying to learn VBA because at my job that's what drives the backbone of our database and our excel workflow (although no one at my division seems to know how any of it works). And i've been trying to write a macro that could automate some of the work i have to do, namely: Importing CSV files into an excel to process them. I've been trying to approach this problem step by step, by dividing into smaller subsets of problems.

So I have been able to add a query into my excel, that allows it to look into a folder to see which files are in there. This allows the macro to 'see' different file paths and filenames.

What i am trying to accomplish now is to have the macro loop through all the files it can see in the folder, and import them to a sheet called 'output'.

No matter what i've tried, and how much research i did, i can't figure out the import macro. It keeps giving me a compile error that it expects '='

(I know that the macro is able to read the filenames etc correctly, because i have created a sub that makes it 'log' whatever it reads, to test its ability to differentiate between file types)

```
Dim ImportFolder As String
Dim ImportRow As Range
Dim ImportFilename As Range
Dim ImportFilenameS As String
Dim ImportAccessDate As Range
Dim ImportFilePath As Range
Dim ImportExtension As Range

Dim ImportRange As Range
Dim ImportVar As Integer
Dim ImportLength As Integer
Dim L

Dim LogRow As Range
Dim LogFilename As Range
Dim LogAccessDate As Range
Dim LogFilePath As Range
Dim LogStatus As Range
Dim LogReason As Range

Dim OutputFolder As String
Dim OutputRange As Range

Sub FileTypeController()

Set ImputFolder = "H:\BLM.Workflow\CSV.Workflow-Input\"

Set ImportExtension = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("B2")
Set ImportFilename = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("A2")
Set ImportAccessDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("C2")
Set ImportFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("G2")

Set LogFilename = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Range("A2")
Set LogAccessDate = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Range("B2")
Set LogFilePath = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Range("C2")

Set LogStatus = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Range("D2")
Set LogReason = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Range("E2")

Set ImportRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Import").Range("A:A")
    ImportVar = WorksheetFunction.CountA(ImportRange)
    ImportLength = (ImportVar - 1)

For L = 1 To ImportLength

    If ImportExtension.Value = ".csv" Or ImportExtension.Value = ".txt" Then 
Call CSVToOutput Else Call ExtensionTypeFailedImport

Set ImportExtension = ImportExtension.Offset(1, 0)

Set ImportFilename = ImportFilename.Offset(1, 0)
Set ImportAccessDate = ImportAccessDate.Offset(1, 0)
Set ImportFilePath = ImportFilePath.Offset(1, 0)

Set LogFilename = LogFilename.Offset(1, 0)
Set LogAccessDate = LogAccessDate.Offset(1, 0)
Set LogFilePath = LogFilePath.Offset(1, 0)


Set LogStatus = LogStatus.Offset(1, 0)
Set LogReason = LogReason.Offset(1, 0)


Next

ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Log").Activate

End Sub

Sub CSVToOutput()

ImportFilenameS = "TEXT;" & ImportFilename.Value
Set OutputRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").Range("A1")

'Application.CutCopyMode = False
With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Output").QueryTables_
    .Add(Connection:= ImportFilenameS,Destination:= OutputRange)
    .Name = "Importfilename"
    .FieldNames = True
    .RowNumbers = False
    .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
    .PreserveFormatting = True
    .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
    .RefreshStyle = xlInsertDeleteCells
    .SavePassword = False
    .SaveData = True
    .AdjustColumnWidth = True
    .RefreshPeriod = 0
    .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
    .TextFilePlatform = 1252
    .TextFileStartRow = 1
    .TextFileParseType = xlDelimited
    .TextFileTextQualifier = xlTextQualifierDoubleQuote
    .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
    .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
    .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = False
    .TextFileCommaDelimiter = True
    .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
    .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array(1)
    .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
    .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False

Call SuccessfulImport
End Sub
```

It's still a first draft, so i haven't taken the time to clean it up a little yet.
Apologies if the code is trash, but, i'm giving it my all ;-)

Comment: I wouldn't want to work for a company that uses 'VBA to drive their database backbone' in 2020 :)

Comment: Oh trust me, it's slow as hell, freezes constantly, but the company has many different pillars, so they basically just gave everyone the bare minimum. Too lazy and cheap to actually develop decent software. I started looking into the code and the person who made it literally left his drafts in there. it's a mess, poorly optimized, and doesn't even automate nearly enough.

Answer (score 0):

At first I spot an error here:

```
Set ImputFolder = "H:\BLM.Workflow\CSV.Workflow-Input\"
```

Reason: you only use the reserved word `Set` with objects, and in this case, you are just assigning a value to a string variable.

Also, I didn't see that variable defined anywhere. Maybe you meant to use this one:

```
Dim ImportFolder As String
```

Those facts aside, I suggest that you look into [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/power-query-overview-and-learning-ed614c81-4b00-4291-bd3a-55d80767f81d). If you have Excel 2010, 2013 you can download it as an add-in or if you have 2016-2019 is already available in the Ribbon's Data tab.

Check Matt’s tutorial on how to combine files from a folder [here](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/combine-csv-files-power-query/)